# Split string in Javascript with _

Tags: javascript

I am beginner with javascript.I want to create array as 1,2,3,4,5

But I get o/p as ,1,2,3,4,5

I tried with .split() in javascript but I am not getting the required output.

```
var string="testrating_1testrating_2testrating_3testrating_4testrating_5";
var temp = new Array();
temp = string.split("testrating_");
for (a in temp ) {
    temp[a] = temp[a];
}
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhFAv/1/)

Comment: Maybe weird things are happening because you don't have `<html>`?

Comment: (Not the problem, but) What's the `for` loop for? Note that there is no need to declare `temp` equal to `new Array()` because that array is never used when on the next line you assign `temp` equal to the return value from `.split()`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it this way:

```
var string = "testrating_1testrating_2testrating_3testrating_4testrating_5",
    temp = string.split('testrating_');

temp.shift(); //remove fist item which is empty 
console.log(temp); //["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The actual value of `temp` is `["","1","2","3","4","5"]`.  This is happening because of `.split` and the string starting with the delimiter.

If you always know the delimiter will be at the start of the string, you can do this, which removes the first element of the Array:

```
temp = string.split("testrating_").slice(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var string="testrating_1testrating_2testrating_3testrating_4testrating_5";
var temp = [];
temp = string.split("testrating_");
var tempNew=[];
for (a in temp ) {
   if(temp[a]!==''){
     tempNew.push(temp[a]);
   }

}
alert(tempNew);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6qHW/)

Comment: Please don't use `new Array()`. Use `[]` - it has several benefits - `new Array(3)` doesn't do quite the same as `[3]`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting ,1,2,3,4,5 because there is no character at the beginning of the string before testrating_ by which you are separating.

either you can remove  testrating_ from first position like statement below

```
var str="1testrating_2testrating_3testrating_4testrating_5";
str.split("testrating_")
```

Or you can remove character from first index after getting result as from array

```
var str="testrating_1testrating_2testrating_3testrating_4testrating_5";
str.split("testrating_").slice(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var string = "testrating_1testrating_2testrating_3testrating_4testrating_5";
var temp = string.split("testrating_").join("").split("").join();
console.log(temp);
```

Can also be done like this:

```
var temp = string.replace(/testrating_/g,"").split("").join();
```

or just:

```
var string = "testrating_1testrating_2testrating_3testrating_4testrating_5";
var temp = string.match(/[\d]/g);   //your regex here
console.log(temp);
```

Not sure about the performance though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string="testrating_1testrating_2testrating_3testrating_4testrating_5";
// Split and remove first entry and return an array
var final = string.split("testrating_").slice(1);
$('#out').text(JSON.stringify(final));
```

Comment: First off, don't use `new Array()`. Use `[]` - it has several benefits - `new Array(3)` doesn't do quite the same as `[3]`

Comment: @JanDvorak - I used the OP code - now edited to remove unnecessary code

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var string="testrating_1testrating_2testrating_3testrating_4testrating_5";
    var temp = new Array();
    temp = string.split("testrating_");

    var output = new Array();
    for (x = 0; x < temp.length; x++) {
        output[x - 1] = temp[x];
    }

    alert(output);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `.splice`:

```
var string="testrating_1testrating_2testrating_3testrating_4testrating_5";
temp = string.split("testrating_"); // temp = ["","1","2","3","4","5"]
temp.splice(0,1) // temp = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
```

What splice does here is goes to the first value in the array (index #0) and removes one value from that point which would be the empty string "".

To give a little more of an explanation, you could remove the empty string and "1" by using splice like so:

`temp.splice(0,2) // temp = ["2","3","4","5"]`

Keep in mind that splice directly effects the array it's called upon and returns an array of values that were removed. So if you did the following:

`values = temp.splice(0,2) // values=["","1"] temp=["2","3","4","5"]`

Also, in this example creating a new array in the following fashion `temp = new Array();` is redundant since `string.split()` effectively creates an array and fills it with the values that were splitted. Keep that in mind going forward. Hope this helps and welcome to the world of programming!